# Cloth animation export Unity Stutter

Tags: animation, physics, unity, cloth-simulation

I'm attempting cloth animation in Blender and exporting to Unity.  My process is as follows:

-Pin one point of the cloth (for it to dangle from) and then apply armature motion to that pinned point

-Simulate cloth physics and export the resulting vertex data as a point cache (.mdd)

-Duplicate the cloth, remove physics, and import point cache data (basically a physics bake)

The animation works perfectly in Blender like so:
[image]

However, when it comes to importing to Unity, something in the export/import process introduces stutter like so:

[image]

Any help debugging this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Leave 'Rig / Animation Type' on 'Generic'
2. Switch to 'Animations', deactivate both 'Resample Curves' and 'Anim. Compression'-checkboxes
3. Switch back to 'Rig / Animation Type', select 'Legacy'
4. Click 'Apply'
5. Check the Animation-Preview - no stuttering!
6. Drag the FBX onto the scene-view-window
7. IMPORTANT: click 'Revert' rather than 'Apply' when asked whether unapplied import settings should be applied

Downsides:

- No 'loop / ping-pong' etc. functionalities (I'll try to create a script-based-solution as a workaround)

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure yet, but I guess I found some sort of a workaround to this issue...
First, import the FBX with the baked-in cloth-animation into Unity, leave the 'Animation Type'-setting on 'Generic'.
Uncheck 'Resample Curves', then apply the changes.
If you preview your cloth-animation, it should play back as supposed to - for now!

In order to 'access' the animation, we need to re-set the 'Animation Type'-setting to 'Legacy', though. This very step would always destroy my 'fluid' animiation.

So I re-imported the FBX, didn't change the 'Animation Type'-Setting, drag-and-dropped it onto the scene.
Now I'd delete the 'Animator', then add the 'Animation'-property.

Now I went back to the imported FBX, re-set the 'Animation Type' to legacy - and it didn't mix things up! It does play back the cloth-sim perfectly fine!

I'll try to write-up a detailed step-by-step guide later on.
Hope this helps anyone else who has been looking for a solution to this problem...

Pardon the bad grammar.